# ` gcloud source repos clone` doesn't work on Compute Instance

Tags: git, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I read [Using Google Cloud Source Repositories with service account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32073764/using-google-cloud-source-repositories-with-service-account) and some other questions, but the solutions don't work for me.

When I `gcloud auth activate-service-account` from my dev machine and used the same
service account, the clone succeeded.  It only fails when running on a Compute Engine
VM.

Here's the error I see:

```
PS C:\Users\user> gcloud source repos clone code
Cloning into 'C:\Users\user\code'...
remote: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Request contains an invalid argument
remote: [type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.LocalizedMessage]
remote: locale: "en-US"
remote: message: "Invalid authentication credentials. Please generate a new identifier: https://source.developers.google.com/new-password"
remote:
remote: [type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.RequestInfo]
remote: request_id: "ffdb284cfa494499929958dcf132e262"
fatal: unable to access 'https://source.developers.google.com/p/my-project/r/code/': The requested URL returned error: 400
ERROR: (gcloud.source.repos.clone) Command '['git', 'clone', 'https://source.developers.google.com/p/my-project/r/code', 'C:\\Users\\user\\code', '--config', 'credential.https://source.developers.google.com/.helper=', '--config', 'credential.https://source.developers.google.com/.helper=!gcloud.cmd auth git-helper --account=my-service-account@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com --ignore-unknown $@']' returned non-zero exit status 128.
```

My VM's scopes:

```
PS C:\Users\user> $x = invoke-restmethod "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/?recursive=true" -Headers @{ "Metadata-Flavor" = "Google" }
PS C:\Users\user> $x.default.scopes
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring.write
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/pubsub
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/source.full_control
PS C:\Users\user> $x."my-service-account@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com".scopes
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring.write
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/pubsub
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/source.full_control
```

gcloud info on the VM:

```
PS C:\Users\user> gcloud info
Google Cloud SDK [387.0.0]

Platform: [Windows, x86_64] uname_result(system='Windows', node='windev', release='2012ServerR2', version='6.3.9600', machine='AMD64')
Locale: ('en_US', 'cp1252')
Python Version: [3.9.12 (tags/v3.9.12:b28265d, Mar 23 2022, 23:52:46) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]]
Python Location: [C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\bundledpython\python.exe]
OpenSSL: [OpenSSL 1.1.1n  15 Mar 2022]
Requests Version: [2.22.0]
urllib3 Version: [1.25.9]
Site Packages: [Disabled]

Installation Root: [C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk]
Installed Components:
  beta: [2022.05.20]
  bq: [2.0.74]
  core: [2022.05.20]
  gcloud: []
  gsutil: [5.10]
System PATH: [C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\sdk;C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.10-Q8;C:\Perl64\site\bin;C:\Perl64\bin;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\ProgramData\GooGet;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin;C:\Program Files\Compute Engine\sysprep;C:\Program Files\Google\Compute Engine\sysprep\;C:\Program Files\Google\Compute Engine\metadata_scripts\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\cygwin64\bin;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\CMake\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38;C:\Users\user\.cargo\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files (x86)\HTML Help Workshop\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.18362.0\x64\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 5\]
Python PATH: [C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\third_party;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\bundledpython\python39.zip;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\bundledpython\DLLs;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\bundledpython\lib;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\bundledpython]
Cloud SDK on PATH: [True]
Kubectl on PATH: [False]

Installation Properties: [C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\properties]
User Config Directory: [C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\gcloud]
Active Configuration Name: [default]
Active Configuration Path: [C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\gcloud\configurations\config_default]

Account: [my-service-account@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com]
Project: [my-project]

Current Properties:
  [core]
    account: [my-service-account@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com] (callback)
    disable_usage_reporting: [False] (property file)
    project: [my-project] (callback)

Logs Directory: [C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\gcloud\logs]
Last Log File: [C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\gcloud\logs\2022.05.29\01.51.04.401135.log]

git: [git version 2.36.1.windows.1]
ssh: [NOT AVAILABLE]
```

With an owner account, I can see the policy I created:

```
PS> gcloud source repos get-iam-policy code
bindings:
- members:
  - serviceAccount:my-service-account@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/source.reader
etag: BwXgG_5PIbk=
version: 1
```

Comment: 1) Verify that the VM has **Allow full access to all Cloud APIs** enabled in the Console GUI so that the **roles/reader** is allowed. 2) Behind the scenes **gcloud** is using git. You might need to set up a git credential helper. **git config --global credential.helper gcloud.sh**

Comment: I verified that Allow full access to all Cloud APIs is enabled in the Console GUI.

Comment: I tried `git config --global credential.helper gcloud.cmd` and that didn't help.

Comment: You may try deleting the gitcookies file which may cause the problems.
You may also refer [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62464440/unable-to-clone-repo-from-google-cloud-source-repository-to-a-compute-engine-ins?answertab=trending#tab-top)

Answer (score 0):

[Vaidehi Jamankar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19075433)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72420534/gcloud-source-repos-clone-doesnt-work-on-compute-instance/73262994#comment128588912_72420534) worked for me:

> You may try deleting the gitcookies file which may cause the problems.

Removing my .gitcookes file fixed the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Follow below two steps

1)gcloud init

2)gcloud source repos clone  --project=project-id